# How to get third relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following models: User, Device, Product.

User

```
  public function devices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Device');
}
```

Device

```
 public function user()
{

    return $this->BelongsTo('App\User');

}

public function reading()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reading', 'device_id', 'part_id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product');
}
```

Product

```
 public function device()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Device');
}
```

The following query pulls my users and all their devices, but inside that collection is not the relation from device to product.

```
$deviceSingles = User::with('devices')->get();
```

This query gets me all the products with all devices assigned to it

```
$deviceSinglesTwo = Product::with('device')->get();
```

How do I get that third relation, attached to my initial query so i can do this

```
$deviceSingles->device->product->title
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax.

```
User::with('devices.product')->get()
```

Comment: i had tried that but i get and mysql error

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.device_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`device_id` in (1, 2)). I must have my columns mixed. there is a product_id in the device table. other tbale, has id,title,product

Comment: @keaner you should check the docs. There's a very strict naming convention for the db columns you need to obey if you don't explicitly specify the foreign key names.

Comment: @keaner because you use `hasOne()` relation, Laravel looks for `device_id` column in the `products` table.

Comment: yeah then one product can only have one device. I need one device can only have one product, but a product can have many devices

Comment: this does not work properly, have a look at my question again please , thanks